# Can iText 7's PdfSweep be used to highlight text?

Tags: java, itext, itext7

Looking through the java iText 7 library, there is a highlight() method in the PdfSweep class. Unfortunately there is little documentation.

Does anyone know if it is therefore possible to not only use use this class to redact, but also to perform highlighting against a regex expression?

Ideally it would be great if we can mark text matching the regex then highlight matches with a style of choice.

Comment: ... what have you tried ?

Comment: I've seen demos with regex patterns, so it should work. I haven't tried it myself though, so I repeat what Benoit wrote: what have you tried?

Comment: Hi - I've actually been able to utilise the same RegexBasedCleanupStrategy in order to find locations, from there I was able to access the canvas and do what I needed.  So everything was looking good up to a point..

Currently I'm investigating an issue with the RegexBasedLocationExtractionStrategy,  this code fires an NPE when it hits line 89 (int endIndex = txt.indexMap.get(mat.end());)